# Not able to run jar file using Iam role without configuring credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, rundeck

I have a jar file which will take input of one ec2 instance id and defined stack name, it will create new ec2 instance and also creates cloud formation stack resources. This is configured and running this jar file via rundeck (2.6.9 version) job. I am using IAM Role to access aws resources and did not configure aws credentials.

All other rundeck jobs which are configured to call aws services are working fine with attached IAM role except this jar file. What should I do to run this jar without configuring aws credentials?

Comment: Hi, more context is needed, what is that jar file exactly? probably that solution *needs* the credentials, in that case you could create some options and pass them as arguments.

Comment: yes that jar file is configured to use credentials. Thats why it is not running when I try to run on EC2 with IAM role attached

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the credentials via [options](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#job-options) in an [inline-script](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) or [command step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#command-step).

1. Create a job.
2. Define the username as an option and the password as a [secure option](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#secure-options) (the password should be stored in the rundeck key storage and then reference it on the secure option).
3. On the command step pass the option using the `${option.myoption}` format (command step) or  `@option.myoption@` format (inline-script step).

I left a job definition example that uses a command step:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 799db92c-00f0-4f02-8d0a-c228daabe839
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JarCredentialsJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - description: '    '
    hidden: true
    name: password
    secure: true
    storagePath: keys/mypassword
    valueExposed: true
  - name: username
    value: myusername
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: java -jar myjarfile.jar -u ${option.username} -p ${option.password}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 799db92c-00f0-4f02-8d0a-c228daabe839
```

Of course, the `java -jar myjarfile.jar -u ${option.username} -p` way to call the jar file is just an example to illustrate how to pass rundeck options. The way of pass the credentials depends on your jar file.